# restful wcf and bindings

Tags: wcf, rest

have some below question about wcf,though visited tones of web pages but could not get the reliable answers.

it would be great if someone help me out in understanding these concepts.

**a.) what is the valid comparison (REST with SOAP) OR (REST with XML.)?**, *as per my understanding (REST with SOAP) is a valid comparison but some posts believes in the later one too.*

**b.) if Rest can use both Json/XML why Soap can not use Json?**, *since Json is a Notation only.*

**c.)in nettcpbinding  binding first response will be serialized into Soap(XML) envelope and then encoded into binary format OR there will be no Soap envelope ?** *(basically wants to understand difference between serialization and encoding )*

Any Example/Link will be highly appreciated.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

Without any tons of explanations, here are my answers.

> a.) what is the valid comparison (REST with SOAP) OR (REST with XML.)?

REST VS SOAP. It's a great debate today. What is important to understand is that they are two completely  differents approaches for web services. Both are valid.
REST seems to be a bit more popular, especially for interop.
XML is simply a file format.

> b.) if Rest can use both Json/XML why Soap can not use Json?

Soap is a contract-based approach. Soap introduces WSDL (Web Services Description Language) :  this describes your service and its operations - what is the service called, which methods does it offer, what kind of in parameters and return values do these methods have. The best way to ensure message validity& coherence is to use Xml and Xsd. Json does not provide this feature.
It was also designed around 2000 where Xml was popular.

> c.)in nettcpbinding binding first response will be serialized into
>   Soap(XML) envelope and then encoded into binary format OR there will
>   be no Soap envelope ?

In every WCF (Soap) bindings, there is a soap enveloppe, because WCF is built on top of it. Binary/Text is releveant to message encoding. This specifies how to transfer data across a network between endpoints. A good explanation is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751889.aspx).